# Random bipartite graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

`RandomGraph[{n,m}]` generates a random graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. I want to generate a random *bipartite* graph, like `RandomBipartiteGraph[m,n,e]`, where I can specify the number of vertices in each partition $m,n$, and the number of edges $e$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution:

```
RandomBipartiteGraph[m_, n_, e_] := 
 Graph[Range[m + n], 
  RandomSample[Flatten@Table[i <-> j, {i, m}, {j, m + 1, m + n}], e]]
```

But I wonder if I can do it with some of Mathematica built-in graph generator functions?

Also, this is very slow if $m$ or $n$ are large. I am generating the list of all *posible* edges, which is a big waste if in the end the actual number of edges is small.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my fast entry:

```
randomBipartiteGraph[m_, n_, e_] :=
 Module[{edges, mat},
  edges = ConstantArray[1, e] ~Join~ ConstantArray[0, m*n - e];
  mat = Partition[RandomSample[edges], m];
  AdjacencyGraph@ArrayFlatten[
    {{0, Transpose[mat]},
     {mat, 0}}
    ]
  ]

Graph[randomBipartiteGraph[10, 20, 80], GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is my simple entry:

```
randomBipartiteGraph[m_, n_, e_] := 
 Graph[Range[m + n], RandomSample[EdgeList@CompleteGraph[{m, n}], e]]
```

Answer (score 5):

[IGraph/M](https://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has two functions for this since version 0.2.0.

```
?IGBipartiteGameGNM
```

> `IGBipartiteGameGNM[n1, n2, m]` generates a bipartite random graph with `n1` and `n2` vertices in the two partitions and `m` edges.

Use this when you know how many edges you want exactly.

```
?IGBipartiteGameGNP
```

> `IGBipartiteGameGNP[n1, n2, p]` generates a bipartite Bernoulli random graph with `n1` and `n2` vertices in the two partitions and connection probability `p`.

Use this when you don't want to fix the number of edges, but instead each edge is present independently with probability $p$.

These functions have two special options:

- `DirectedEdges` controls whether they should produce a directed graph
- `"Bidirectional"` controls whether edges should run in both directions between the partitions, or only in one direction, when generating directed graphs.

---

Example:

```
g = IGBipartiteGameGNM[5, 6, 14, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
IGBipartiteQ[g]
(* True *)
```

```
IGBipartitePartitions[g]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}} *)
```

---

Be aware that Mathematica's [`BipartiteGraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BipartiteGraphQ.html) has a bug where it sometimes incorrectly (and apparently randomly!!) reports `False` for directed graphs.  This means that `GraphLayout -> "BipariteEmbedding"` will also fail to properly visualize these graphs.  So if you get a graph from these functions that doesn't visualize, it is due to this Mathematica bug, not a problem with the package.  The graph is still usable as usual.  An example of such an incorrectly handled graph is `AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}]`.

Workarounds: use `IGBipartiteQ` for testing bipartiteness and use `IGLayoutBipartite` for visualization.