# Is this a bug between RelationGraph and BipartiteGraphQ?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

[Inspired by yode's latest question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111911/2305) I was playing around with `RelationGraph` and found that `BipartiteQ` seems to be unable to detect certain bipartite results.

As an example, I was looking at the graph where each vertex is a 1- or 2-digit integer, and edges indicate whether a 2-digit integer starts or ends with a 1-digit integer. This is clearly a bipartite graph (and `GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"` shows this), since there are no edges between 2-digit numbers and no edges between single digits. And up to `n = 19` this works fine:

```
g = RelationGraph[(StringEndsQ[#1, #2] || StringStartsQ[#2, #])
   && # != #2 &, ToString /@ Range[0, 19], 
 GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
BipartiteGraphQ @ g
(* True *)
```

But as soon as I get to 20:

```
g = RelationGraph[(StringEndsQ[#1, #2] || StringStartsQ[#2, #])
   && # != #2 &, ToString /@ Range[0, 20], 
 GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
BipartiteGraphQ @ g
(* False *)
```

The problem seems to be something internal to the result of `RelationGraph`, since extracting the edges and reconstructing the graph works:

```
BipartiteGraphQ @ Graph @ EdgeList @ g
(* True *)
```

We can however localise the problem a bit by computing the graph on a smaller set of vertices. It's possible to remove all but 6 vertices/edges and still reproduce the problem:

```
g = RelationGraph[(StringEndsQ[#1, #2] || StringStartsQ[#2, #])
   && # != #2 &, ToString /@ {0, 1, 2, 10, 12, 20}, 
 GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
BipartiteGraphQ @ g
(* False *)
```

Removing any further edges "resolves" the problem.

Is this a bug in `BipartiteGraphQ`? Am I misunderstanding something about bipartite graphs?

I'm using Mathematica 10.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: See the end of my answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109437/12

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah okay, so it's a known issue. Interestingly, in all the cases I've tried, `GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"` still worked without an issue.

Comment: BTW I reported that as CASE:3531918 on Feb 13 and they told me that the problem was already known.  I didn't read your post in detail and I don't know if it is the same bug.  I also complained here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=27550013#27550013

Comment: BTW [IGraph/M](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97233/12) has `IGBipartiteQ` precisely for this reason.  <del>But you should know that it is much slower than the built-in function because converting a Mathematica graph to an igraph one is a huge overhead.</del>  ... Well, I just tested, and for huge graphs it is in fact faster than `BipartiteGraphQ` *despite* that conversion overhead!!

Comment: Just for the record, this can still be reproduced in 11.0.